# Inferring effect & effect modification from simulation data

Tags: interaction, generalized-estimating-equations, sensitivity-analysis

I have a "black box" system (computer simulation), which takes inputs: $x_1 \in [0,1]$, $x_2 \in [0,1]$, and $N_i$ others $\vec\theta = \{\theta_1, \dots, \theta_{N_i}\}$, and produces an output $y \in [0,1]$. I know that for fixed $x_2$ and $\vec\theta$, $y$ is monotonic increasing in $x_1$, and similarly for fixed $x_1$ and $\vec\theta$, $y$ is monotonic increasing in $x_2$. Both relationships could be approximated as linear or with a low-order spline, and there should be no intercept ($x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$ implies $y=0$). The other inputs $\vec\theta$ should really only act as effect modifiers, not independent predictors of $y$.

I'd like to infer a) the expected effect of $x_1$, $x_2$ on $y$ over a known range of $\theta$; and b) whether this effect is modified by any elements of $\vec\theta$.

#### Questions

- What statistical model should I use?
- What sampling strategy for $x_1$, $x_2$, and $\vec\theta$ should I use to best support the model? I can get ~1000s of samples easily.

#### Current Approach

I get $N_j$ samples of $\vec\theta$ using [latin-hypercube sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_hypercube_sampling) to get good coverage of the space. Then, for each sample $\vec\theta_j$, I use latin-hypercube sampling again to get $N_k$ samples of $(x_1,x_2)_{jk}$. Running the simulation for each complete sample, I get $N_j \times N_k$ values of $y_{jk}$, where $\vec\theta$ is shared across $k$. Then, I use a [GEE GLM](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geepack/versions/1.3.3/topics/geeglm) model, with "ID" = $j$, and the following equation:
$$y = \beta_{1,0}~x_1 + \sum_i\beta_{1,i}~x_1\theta_i + \beta_{2,0}~x_2 + \sum_i\beta_{2,i}~x_2\theta_i + \beta_{1,2}~x_1x_2$$
($jk$ omitted for clarity).
From this approach, the value and significance of the parameters $\beta_{1,0}$, $\beta_{2,0}$, and $\beta_{1,2}$ allow me to answer (a), and likewise the interaction terms $\beta_{1,i}$, $\beta_{2,i}$, $\dots$ allow me to answer (b). Is this a valid / efficient strategy?

Thanks,

#### Bonus: Plot

If helpful, here is a plot of $y$ vs $x_1$ (left) and $y$ vs $x_2$ (right), coloured by the value of a particular $\theta_i$.

[image: plot]

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable given that you know that the response is approximately linear. Is there a reason you are not satisfied with it ? also, what are questions (a) and (b) that you refer to ?

Comment: Thanks. No specific reason. Just not very confident, so I was worried I might be missing something obvious. And I want to move forward with writing the paper... (a) and (b) refer to the 2nd paragraph.